# Static class in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, static, typescript

Is there any way to create an static class in typescript, node.js

I want to create an static class to keep all constants and string in that.

what could be the best way to do that ?

Comment: Is there any issue with just using an object?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Sure you can define a class with static properties:

```
export class Constants {
    static MAX_VALUE = 99999;
    static MIN_VALUE = 0;
}
```

Then use it when you need:

```
import { Constants } from '../constants';
console.log(Constants.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: this is something I was looking for, Thanks Man

Answer (score 7):

You can put your variables and functions you want inside a module which means that it doesn't have to be instantiated.

```
module constants {
   export var myValue = 'foo';

   export function thisIsAStaticLikeFunction () {
      console.log('function called');
   }
}

.....
console.log(constants.myValue);
```

There really is no such thing as a true static class, but this comes pretty close to replicating it.

Comment: +1 Very good, thank you! Solved my problem of accessing static member of a subclass like so: `App.Commands.mainMenuCommand`.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use Enums like that:

```
export enum Numbers {
   Four = 4,
   Five = 5,
   Six = 6,
   Seven = 7
}
```

Then use it:

```
import { Numbers } from './Numbers';
Numbers.FIVE
```

Comment: Should be the accepted and correct answer. Others were right about the equivalent to static classes in typescript, but for the purpose of the thread opener, this should be the way to go.